# custom destination for certain authorization exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a configuration where access to certain parts of the website requires a certain role: ROLE_A.

In order to get this role you need to fill out a certain form.

Users can also pass through initial registration without receiving ROLE_A and subsequently try to access these areas that require ROLE_A. Now, I just present them with a login form informing them they don't have sufficient access rights.

What I would like to achieve is that for user to get automatically redirected to the form they need to fill out to "upgrade to ROLE_A". So, that I can process the upgrade and move them along.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with an interceptor in spring. Check out in the spring docs how to setup an interceptor... it's pretty simple. Interceptors implement the HandlerInterceptor interface. In the preHandle method you can perform processing on requests prior to the request reaching the controller. So in your case, you can write code in the preHandle method of the interceptor to check the user's role and if they are not ROLE_A, then you can redirect them to the form. Something like the following would do nicely:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    // get the user's role from the session
    String role = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("userRole");

    // validate user session when attempting to access pages
    String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
    // place all links in the if statement that you do not want users to be able to access without loggin in
    if (servletPath.endsWith("protectedPage.html")) {
        // make sure the user has a valid session
        if (role == null || !"ROLE_A".equals(role)) {
            // when the session is not valid (eg. session timed out, etc.) redirect user to index page
            response.sendRedirect("roleAForm.html");
    return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses my issue. There are a groups of pages that require ROLE_A, so I think would need to be able to reference the intercept-url object and be able to say: "does this resource require ROLE_A" and "does this user have ROLE_A". Perhaps I could load the filterSecurityMetadataSource in this interceptor and query that

Comment: We usually store user roles in a table. So when the user logs in we retrieve and store all pertinent information about that user in his session (permissions, roles, etc.). I suppose their would have to be another object that maps pages to their required roles that your application has access to also. Maybe an enum or something like that so you don't have to query the database every time you want to check user roles.

Answer (score 1):

1. First create your own custom accessDenied Handlder.

   ```html
   public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    
    private String redirectPage;

    public void setRedirectPage(String redirectPage) {
     this.redirectPage = redirectPage;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect to our redirectPage page instead of login page.
     */
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response,
      AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
      ServletException {
      String redirectUrl = request.getContextPath()+redirectPage;
            redirectUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(redirectUrl);
     
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
     
    }
    
    

   }
   ```

@. Define bean for this custom handler into spring-security.xml file.   and inject redirect page URL to this custom handler.

```html
<beans:bean id = "accessDeniedHandler" class = "com.own.web.security.handler.CustomAccessDeniedHandler">
  <beans:property name="redirectPage" value="/rediectPage" />
 </beans:bean>
```

3. Define access Denied handler tag into spring-security.xml file and refer this customAccessDenied handler bean id.

   ```html
   <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
   ```
4. User should have role to access the page your want to redirect

Comment: Ok, I already have a custom access denied handler. But the point is how to determine for this particular resource that access is denied because the user is missing ROLE_A?

Comment: Use this annotation.         @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_A')")   and put this annotation on the method on controller..if user is missing ROLE_A and try to access this method in controller. then spring redirect him to access denied handler

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I ended up doing:

```
    public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Inject
    @Named("securityMetadataSource")
    SecurityMetadataSource securityMetadata;

    @Override
    public void handle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        IUser user = RequestUtils.getUser(request);

        //The user is probably logged in but tried to enter an area he had no access to.        
        if(user != null){

            /*
             * Check to see if this resource required endUserAccess
             */
            FilterInvocation fi = new FilterInvocation(request.getContextPath(), request.getServletPath(), null);

            boolean requireEndUser = false;
            for(ConfigAttribute attr : securityMetadata.getAttributes(fi)){
                String expression = attr.toString();
                if(expression != null && expression.contains("ROLE_ENDUSER")){
                    requireEndUser = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            /*
             * We have been denied access because we're missing the correct role 
             */
            if(requireEndUser){
                response.sendRedirect(URLUtils.addContextPath("/register/upgrade", request));
                return;
            }

        }
        response.sendRedirect(URLUtils.addContextPath(URLUtils.getLogin(request),request));
    }
}
```